# nestJs FileInterceptor and DTO

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs

I want to create upload with swagger,use DTO and save the binary in my MongoDB

My DTO is:

```js
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { Expose } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsNotEmpty, IsOptional } from 'class-validator';


export class GatewayDto {  
    
  @ApiProperty({ default: 'foo' })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Expose()
  name: string;
  
  @ApiProperty({default: 'XXXX:YYYY'})
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Expose()
  token: string;

  @ApiProperty({default: '123'})
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Expose()
  channelId: string;
  
  @ApiProperty({ default: true })  
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Expose()
  public: string;

  @Expose()  
  @IsNotEmpty()
  logo: any;

}
```

my controller is:

```js
 @Post('/')
    @ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
    @ApiBody({
        schema: {
            type: 'object',
            properties: {
                name: {
                    type: 'string',
                    default: 'foo'
                },
                token: {
                    type: 'string',
                    default: '11:22'
                },
                channelId: {
                    type: 'string',
                    default: '1234'
                },
                public: {
                    type: 'string',
                    default: 'true'
                },
                logo: {
                    type: 'string',
                    format: 'binary',                                        
                },
            },
        },
    })
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('logo'))
    @HttpCode(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @ApiCreatedResponse(GatewayConfigSwagger.API_CREATE_GATEWAY)
    //@Serialize(GatewayDto)
    public async create(
        @UploadedFile('file') file,
        @Body() data: GatewayDto,
        @Request() request
    ) {
        console.log(data);
        
        if (file) {
            data['logo'] = file.buffer;
        }
        //return this.gatewayService.create(request.user.userId._id, data);
    }
```

When I create my request, I get this error:

`"logo should not be empty"`

My curl is:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:3001/api/v1/gateways' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxx \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'name=foo' \
  -F 'token=11:22' \
  -F 'channelId=1234' \
  -F 'public=true' \
  -F 'logo=@image.png;type=image/png'
```

If I remove the logo field from DTO I'm able to store my image.

I tried to create a interceptor according to this answer [File uploading along with other data in Swagger NestJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66605192/file-uploading-along-with-other-data-in-swagger-nestjs)

```js
import { BadGatewayException, CallHandler, ExecutionContext, Injectable, NestInterceptor, UnauthorizedException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { catchError, map, Observable, throwError } from "rxjs";

export interface Response<T> {
    statusCode: number;
    data: T;    
}

@Injectable()
export class FileExtender implements NestInterceptor {
    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
      const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
      console.log(req.body)
      
      return next.handle();
    }
  }
```

and my req.body doesn't have logo field

**UPDATE**

I updated my interceptor with

```js
import { BadGatewayException, CallHandler, ExecutionContext, Injectable, NestInterceptor, UnauthorizedException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { catchError, map, Observable, throwError } from "rxjs";

export interface Response<T> {
    statusCode: number;
    data: T;    
}

@Injectable()
export class FileExtender implements NestInterceptor {
    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
      const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
      
      req.body['logo'] = req.file.buffer;   
      console.log(req.body)
      
      return next.handle();
    }
  }
```

Now it works, but is it the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `@IsOptional` validator on the `logo` property in the DTO file. It is used to mark nullable fields. Validation will pass if it is `null` or `undefined` and will be enforced as per other validators otherwise. Application logic must handle this accordingly.

You can take a look at all available validators [here](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator). You can combine any number of them on any DTO class property.